# Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, afnetworking

I am using AFnetworking library to post data on server.

Following is my code to post data on server.

```
- (void) callLoginAPI:(NSDictionary *)dictProfile{
    // 1
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[dictProfile valueForKey:@"name"], @"username",
                                                                    [dictProfile valueForKey:@"first_name"],@"first_name",
                                                                    [dictProfile valueForKey:@"last_name"],@"last_name",
                                                                    [dictProfile valueForKey:@"email"],@"email",
                                                                    [dictProfile valueForKey:@"birthday"],@"dob",
                                                                    [dictProfile valueForKey:@"gender"],@"gender",
                                                                    [[dictProfile valueForKey:@"location"] valueForKey:@"name"],@"location",
                                                                    [dictProfile valueForKey:@"timezone"],@"timezone",
                                                                    @"",@"language",
                                                                    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large",[dictProfile valueForKey:@"id"]],@"profile_pic_url",
                                                                    @"",@"cover_pic_url",nil];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

    [manager POST:@"http://10.1.81.35:8000/api/login/" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

and in response I got following error

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" UserInfo=0x7c87b6f0 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7cc220e0> { URL: http://10.1.81.35:8000/api/login/ } { status code: 400, headers {
    Allow = "POST, OPTIONS";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Tue, 07 Oct 2014 10:45:08 GMT";
    Server = "WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.6";
    Vary = "Accept, Cookie";
    "X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://10.1.81.35:8000/api/login/, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400), com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b226465 7461696c 223a2022 4a534f4e 20706172 73652065 72726f72 202d204e 6f204a53 4f4e206f 626a6563 7420636f 756c6420 62652064 65636f64 6564227d>}
```

I am not able to understand why I got the such kind of error. What is missing in my code?

Comment: Did you get the problem ? I am facing same problem. Can you please look into my code.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713116/errorrequest-failed-bad-request-400-login-via-afnetworking-in-swift

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error says it all: you got a [400 response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) from the server, meaning that what you sent was either not formatted properly, or the server just couldn't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Please add this line to your code,
i hope it help you.

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced the same issue. In my case its only for upload Image with larger size. Our server has limited with max.upload size. I resized the image and uploaded, and the issue is gone.

You can resize the image with:

```
+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image
              scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```