# Passing Parameters Using AFNetworking in swift

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking-3, afhttpsessionmanager

**What I did:-**

1.I want to call the services using **AFHTTPSessionManager**

2.I want to pass the parameters only in **JSON** Format using **POST** method
  and  I have also tried to pass the parameters as **JSON** but I was receiving      **Bad Request**

3.Using AFNetworking 3.0

4. Referred link [Convert Dictionary to JSON in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625133/convert-dictionary-to-json-in-swift)

MY CODE:-

```
     dict = ["email_id":user! , "password": pass!]

  do {
                jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
                // here "jsonData" is the dictionary encoded in JSON data
                 theJSONText = String(data: jsonData!,
                                           encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
                print("json string = \(theJSONText)")


            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }



     manager.POST(urlString, parameters: theJSONText as String!, success:
                {
                    requestOperation, response in

                    let result = NSString(data: response as! NSData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

                    print(result)
                },
                         failure:
                {
                    requestOperation, error in
                    //let result = NSString(data: error as! NSData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

                    print(error)

            })
```

WHAT I WANT TO DO:-
              I want to pass the parameter as JSON Format

```
      Printing description of theJSONText:
"{\n  \"email_id\" : \"bbh\",\n  \"password\" : \"vh\"\n}"
```

After Converting to JSON STRING also I'm not getting in JSON Format

please help me to do this..

Comment: why u take too much complication, you can directly pass the dict to param

Comment: I want send like JSON format

Comment: dict also passed as JSON format

Comment: I have tried as u said but it is also not working

Comment: can you update the question once

Comment: {
  "email_id" : "",
  "password" : ""
}

Comment: I want to pass like this if i passed like dictionary I had getting only error

Comment: it means check your `user` and `pass ` contains values or not

Comment: what the error u faced

Comment: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)"

Comment: NO I'm giving the right user and pass

Comment: for your erroro see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235270/error-domain-com-alamofire-error-serialization-response-code-1011-request-fail

Comment: Ya its correct that's my problem is   that what i sent was either not formatted properly, or the server just couldn't understand it. My JSON IS not valid

Answer (score 0):

remove below line from code,

```
  theJSONText = String(data: jsonData!,
                                       encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
            print("json string = \(theJSONText)")
```

Set option to `0` instead of `NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted` in json serialization

and pass `jsonData`(as a data) as a parameter instead of `theJSONText`.

**Update :**

Try like this,

```
 let urlString = "http://example.com/file.php"
 let dictionary = ["key1": [1,2,3], "key2": [2,4,6]]

var error: NSError?
 let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dictionary, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.allZeros, error: &error)
let jsonString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let parameters = ["data" :  jsonString!]

let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
manager.responseSerializer = AFHTTPResponseSerializer()
manager.POST(urlString, parameters: parameters, success:
{
    requestOperation, response in

    let result = NSString(data: response as! NSData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    println(result)
},
failure:
{
    requestOperation, error in
})
```

in this example response is in string, If response in json format then you should serialize it in json using `nsjsonserialization` instead of string

Hope this will help :)

Comment: I had removed that line and add             jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions(rawValue: 0))

Comment: instead of NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted now also i'm getting the same issue BAD REQUEST

Comment: You should use `postman` to check your web service then, so you can know which format of data accept by your web service

Comment: I have checked in Postman also..okay i have an another I had set content type *        manager.requestSerializer.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")* like this in AFhttpsession manager using AFNetworking 3 is this way to set content type is correct or want to use *       manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = NSSet(objects:"application/json") as? Set<String>
*

Comment: Comment that line and then try like i suggest in answer

Comment: If i comment that line means its showing an error set the content-type

Comment: there shouldn't content type to response. requests have content type

Comment: I had removed  the content type its showing an error "Request failed: unacceptable (406)" ..At request time  I think I want to set content type but if   I set the content type it's shows an error Request failed:Bad Request (400)..