# Error:Request failed: bad request (400) login via afnetworking in swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, authentication, afnetworking

I am new to swift and trying to login via AFNetworking which is working fine with Postman.

```
let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager(baseURL: NSURL(string: "****"))
manager.requestSerializer = AFHTTPRequestSerializer()
manager.requestSerializer = AFHTTPRequestSerializer()

let params = ["user":username,"password":password]

manager.POST("/api/LoginApi/appLogin", parameters: params, success:
    {
        requestOperation, response in

        let result = NSString(data: response as! NSData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

        print(result)
    },failure: {
        requestOperation, error in print(error)
```

Can somebody mark the issue with this code !!

Comment: Check your param list you are sending in login request.

Comment: Username, password.. checked !! On postman, I am logining In with same username password.

Comment: This is a very vague situation. 400 is a bad request, which means in your request you are sending some incorrect data.

Comment: Yes, Very true.. But, what is incorrect I am not getting that.. I checked Baseurl, API, Username & Password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are post json with afnetwork 3.0

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[manager POST:url parameters:parametersDictionary progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"success!");
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    }];
```